# Given its body functions, create an instance of a type class (or workaround)

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I would like to have a State Monad, where I keep a list of modes.

```
data State = S { 
      modes :: [Mode]
}
```

However, I have two requirements:

1. Mode needs to be a parametrized with a type.
2. Mode can be built on run time.

Here is how I tried to convince GHC:

**Attempt 1**, with a data type

```
data Mode a = Mode { 
      complF :: String -> IO [String]
      action :: State -> String -> X a
}

data State a = S { 
      modes :: [Mode a]
}

initState :: (String -> IO [String]) -> (State -> String -> X a) -> State a
initState c a = {
      modes = [buildMode c a]
}

buildMode :: (String -> IO [String]) -> (State -> String -> X a) -> Mode a
buildMode c a = {
       complF = c
     , action = a
}
```

Good.. however, this is not useful for me, since every mode has to be of type `Mode a` inside a `State a`. Meaning that no `Mode String` and `Mode ()` can co-exist within a State.

**Attempt 2**:, type class

```
class Mode a where
       complF :: String -> IO [String] 
       action :: State -> String -> X a

data State = S {
       modes :: (Mode a) => [a]
}
```

But, now I don't know how to build a mode in run time given `complF` and `action`. It seems that instances of type classes must be defined at compile time.

```
instance Mode DefaultMode where
       complF :: .. 
       action :: ..
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: You can create run-time instances with http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection, but it's not easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If modes support a fixed API, you can use an [existential type](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/ExistentialQuantification) to hide their representation type. E.g.

```
data State = S { 
  modes :: forall a . ModeLike a => [Mode a]
}
```

and then implement a class `ModeLike` that has only those operations supported by `Mode` types. Your 2nd attempt is close to this.

Since type class instances are open, you add new instances without changing your code.

If you have, however, a fully dynamic system -- i.e. you cannot enumerate the types that will be possible modes - you will have to use a dynamic type as one of the instances.